# How do I overcome 'Time limit exceeded' error on LeetCode on the daily temperatures problem?

Tags: java, arrays

Daily temperature problem with sample i/o

```
Input: temperatures = [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73]
Output: [1,1,4,2,1,1,0,0]
```

I'm a beginner and was trying to do this without stack. Is it possible?

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] dailyTemperatures(int[] temperatures) 
    {
        int l=temperatures.length;
        int answer[]=new int[l];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            int c=0;int j;int f=0;
            if(i==l-1)
            answer[i]=0;
            else
            {
            for(j=i+1;j<l;j++)
            {
                if(temperatures[i]<temperatures[j])
                {
                    c++;
                    f=1;
                    break;
                }
                if(temperatures[i]>=temperatures[j])
                {
                    c++;
                    f=0;
                }
            }
            if(f!=0)
            answer[i]=c;
            else
            answer[i]=0;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

the code failed for 1 test class :( resulting in the error

Comment: "*How do i overcome 'Time limit exceeded' error*" using a different, faster algorithm -- I do not know what the "*daily temperatures problem*" is, your question is missing its description, so hard to help more. BTW this site is not the *best* for such kind of question, regarding optimization of code

Comment: As we don't know what the problem is, hard to say. But the timelimits on leetcode (and similar sites) are typically to sort out the straight forward/brute force approaches.

Comment: Here is the [temperature problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/) description

Comment: If your code works, it might be better for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Check out their requirements before posting.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Sorry I failed to read the title. You are correct, the question seems fine for Code Review.

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for a solution that does not use a stack **and** runs in less than O(n^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can solved without a stack by using the fact that all temperatures are in the range [30, 100]. We can iterate backwards and store the nearest index each temperature occurred at and essentially solve by brute force.

```java
public int[] dailyTemperatures(int[] temperatures) {
    final int MAX_TEMP = 100;
    int[] next = new int[MAX_TEMP + 1], ans = new int[temperatures.length];
    for (int i = temperatures.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int temp = temperatures[i];
        for (int j = temp + 1; j <= MAX_TEMP; j++)
            if (next[j] != 0 && (ans[i] == 0 || next[j] - i < ans[i])) 
                ans[i] = next[j] - i;
        next[temp] = i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: I do not see the point of trying to solve this without a stack though. Knowing the brute force solution is not very useful.

Comment: *"Knowing the brute force solution is not very useful"* Indeed. The O/P seems to be looking for a solution that runs without a stack *and* meets a time constraint.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer This does meet the time constraint. You can try submitting it.